# Rails how to expire a directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, will-paginate

**How to expire a directory in Rails?**

I have a blog where `/posts/` lists all the posts. Controller posts, action index. Pretty standard stuff.

Posts are paginated in groups of 10 using will_paginate.

The pages are being cached like this:

```
/posts/
/posts/index/2
/posts/index/3
/posts/index/4
...
/posts/index/134
/posts/index/135
... 
etc..
```

When I need to expire this pages, `expire_page(posts_path)` won't do the job, it will only expire `/posts.html`.

**What's the best way to expire the paginated pages?** Since there is an undetermined number of pages, should I just expire the whole `/posts/index/` directory? **How can I expire a directory**?

*thanks*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing page caching, right?  Why not just delete the directory?

```
system("rm -rf #{RAILS_ROOT}/public/posts")
#Or, in more Rubyish code
FileUtils.rm_rf "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/posts"
```

Comment: I ended up doing something very similar to your answer, it pointed me to the right direction, thank you. I found out page caching can turn into a nightmare if you have a lot of controllers and sweepers.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a Regexp to expire_fragment:

```
expire_fragment(r%{/posts/index/\d+})
```

But be warned that only works when your cache store is capable of iterating over all keys. For example, it doesn't work with `memcached`.

Edit: I see this is page caching, not fragment caching. It seems expire_page does not accept a Regexp. Hmm.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a sweeper to run when you need to expire those pages.  Check out this Rails Envy post http://railsenvy.com/2007/02/28/rails-caching-tutorial#sweepers

If you can't remove your pages with some set of hash params, then there is an example of removing an entire directory of cached files at http://railsenvy.com/2007/02/28/rails-caching-tutorial#clearing

There might be some more info in that article that could help you, it is a really good 2 part explanation of all Rails caching.